# Could not find generator migraton

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This morning I started getting this error when trying to generate migration files:

```
$ rails generate migraton add_opp_inquiry_date inquiry_date:string
Could not find generator migraton.
```

I don't know where to begin looking for what caused this - a beginner sorry. Any suggestions would be really helpful. I'm running the command from the correct directory.

Have tried looking through old threads and the common theme is people leaving out "migration" - which I'm not.

Thanks

Comment: rails g migration add_opp_inquiry_date inquiry_date:string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled **migration**.  Try this:

```
rails generate migration add_opp_inquiry_date inquiry_date:string
```